# High Firebase Downloads

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a React Native app that has 2k users. All user data is stored in Firebase in the following format:
[image: Firebase data structure]

So each user has a list of Fasts, where they generally create one fast per day. A very small amount of data. This is what my Database Usage graph looks like:

[image: Firebase Usage]

Some observations:

- On the 27th, 134MB was downloaded. The total database size is .5MB. 134MB/.5MB = 268 times that the entire database was downloaded. This means each user would have downloaded their data 268 times, which is highly unlikely. My Firebase rules:
  [image: Firebase rules]
  So it's not possible users are downloading other users' data.
  I ran Firebase Profiler for ~11 mins:
  [image: Firebase Profiler]

I'm stumped. Finally, here's my one file that does almost every Firebase operation besides logging in/out:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import moment from 'moment'
import {
  currentFastChanged,
  setGraphData,
  setAllData,
  targetFastChanged,
  setLastFastEnd,
usernameChanged,} from '../actions/actions'
// Initialize Firebase
var firebaseConfig = {
};
export const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

function syncFirebase(store) {

  firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user)
    {
      getUserRef().child('TargetFast').on('value', (snap) => {
        store.dispatch(targetFastChanged(snap.val() ? snap.val() : 15));
      });

      getUserRef().child('Fasts').on('value', (snap) => {
        var items = [];
        snap.forEach((child) => {
          items.push({
            start: child.val().Start,
            end: child.val().End,
            _key: child.key
          });
        });

        items.sort(function(a, b) {
           return parseInt(b.start) - parseInt(a.start);
       });
       store.dispatch(setGraphData(createGraphData(items, store.getState().myReducer.targetFast)));
       store.dispatch(setLastFastEnd(getLastFastEnd(items)));
       store.dispatch(setAllData(items));
     });

     getUserRef().child('CurrentFast').on('value', (snapshot) => {
       store.dispatch(currentFastChanged(snapshot.val()));
     });

   });

    }
  })

}

function getUserRef()
{
  return firebaseApp.database().ref('Users/' + firebaseApp.auth().currentUser.uid);
}

function createGraphData(items, targetFast) {

 var graphItems = [];
 var idx = 0;
 for(idx = 0; idx < 7 && idx < items.length; idx++)
 {
   var item = items[idx];
   graphItems.push({
     duration : moment.duration(item.end - item.start).asHours(),
     label : moment(item.start).format('ddd'),
     item : item
   });
 }

 while(graphItems.length < 7)
 {
   var add = targetFast * .2 * (Math.random() - .5);
   var randomVal = targetFast + add
   graphItems.push({duration : randomVal, label : "na", color : 'lightgrey', });
 }
  return graphItems.reverse();
}

function getLastFastEnd(items) {
  return items.length && items[0].end;
}

export function setCurrentFastRef(val)
{
  getUserRef().child('CurrentFast').set(val);
  //firebaseApp.database().ref('Users/' + firebaseApp.auth().currentUser.uid + '/CurrentFast').set(val);
}

export function pushNewFast(start, end)
{
  getUserRef().child('Fasts').push({'Start': start, 'End': end, 'Publish' : true})
}

export function editFastRef(key, start, end)
{
  getUserRef().child('Fasts').child(key).set({'Start' : start, 'End' : end});
}

export function deleteFastRef(key)
{
  getUserRef().child('Fasts').child(key).remove();
}

export function setTargetFastRef(val)
{
  getUserRef().child('TargetFast').set(val);
}

module.exports = firebaseApp;
module.exports.sync = syncFirebase;
module.exports.serverTimestamp = firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
```

My bill is already at $1 for about 15 days for what seems like a trivial amount of data. My current suspicions are:

- Listeners are just stacking up and downloading data many times. The listeners aren't being deleted
- Overhead that's not my fault (SSL?)
- ??? Any ideas?

Comment: The best bet here would be to open a Firebase support ticket and include your project ID, https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/ - they can take a look at the reporting in more details and help break it down.

Comment: Re some of the ideas: SSL is definitely a part of it, but you'd have to be tearing up and down the connection a lot. The stacking listeners idea shouldn't matter as long as they're using the same connection. Can you put in some logging around your initialization? May also be worth considering one of the RN wrappers that wrap the native iOS and Android SDKs, as then you would get on-device caching.

Comment: I've made a Firebase support ticket. I'd also like to note that the shape of the Downloads chart is the same as the shape of my user signups chart. I currently have 2k users, but 10 days ago I only had 1k users.

Comment: There are some useful docs in the DB guide (already noted by the OP): [Understanding Realtime Database Billing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/billing) and [Profiling Your Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile).

Comment: How many times per day would a typical user open your app?

Comment: I would expect a user to open the app twice per day. Once to start a fast, and once to end a fast.

Comment: Firebase support said that it looks like SSL overhead is the culprit. He said that each new connection is 3.5KB. So (134MB / (3.5KB / 1000)) / 2000Users = 19 new connections per user per day (disregarding actual data download).  This seems within the realm of possibility. So the cost right now is $.02/user/year, which seems rational.

Comment: I am only using Realtime DB for sports live feed app. Sports data for live matches updated every other second. I even optimised db performance using their guide. There is 1 GB download with only 4 test users. Am I doing something wrong or should I choose SOCKET.IO or Parser?

Comment: Hey @Mark - how did this work out for you in the end? Did it scale okay with regard to data amount? 
I imagine if it was mainly SSL overhead, then adding subsequent data made only a comparatively small change to the download amounts?

Comment: It did work out in the end. I sold the app so I don't have details, but I had 15k DAU and Firebase cost was rational.